# Java set value in array get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: java, android

in my application i have this Arrays:

```
private static String[] I_DAYS;
private static String[] I_MONTH = { "31", "31", "31", "31", "31", "31", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "29" };
```

by this below codes i can set value into array:

```
int currentDay = Integer.parseInt(SDate[0].substring(8, 10));
setDay(setRange(1, Integer.parseInt(I_MONTH[currentMonth])));
setCurrentDayValue(currentDay);
```

in first time i dont have problem, i want to set other value into this array, but in this time `I_DAYS` array lenght maybe random and i want to set value into that by :

```
int min = 1;
int max = 30;
if (currentValue <= 7) {
    min = 1;
    max = 29;
}
if (currentValue == 12) {
    min = 1;
    max = 28;
}
setDay(setRange(min, max));
```

unfortunately i get error when i try to set value for this functions:

```
public void setDay(String[] day) {
    I_DAYS = new String[day.length];
    I_DAYS = day;
    setDefaultValues(np_day, day);
}
private void setDefaultValues(NumberPicker picker, String[] values) {
    picker.setMaxValue(values.length - 1);
    picker.setMinValue(0);
    picker.setDisplayedValues(values);
    picker.setFocusable(true);
    picker.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
}
```

LogCat:

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=29; index=29

this error cause of when i try to set currentValue to 1 from 12

Comment: Why was this tagged `photoshop`?

Comment: @Sirko oh i'm sorry sir, i'm edited post

Comment: I think there will be a few more exceptions to come as you run this code more. All of the same type (_ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException_)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the rest of your code, but somewhere in it I guess you start trying to loop through your array with a 1 instead of a 0.

In Java, arrays are zero-indexed. So a an array of size 29 goes from 0-28. Accessing index 29 causes an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception.

In fact, re looking at your code, I can see the error.

It's here

```
if (currentValue <= 7) {
    min = 0;
    max = 29;
}
```

it should be

```
if (currentValue <= 7) {
    min = 0;
    max = 28;
}
```

Comment: Why? can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

that's normal, you gave `I_DAYS` an index `setDay(setRange(min, max));` which is in the case of `12` will be from 1 to 28 which represents a length of **29**, then you try to change it to `1`(or any number less than `7`) which will try to give it a range from 1 to 29 (requires array with a length of **30**), so you got `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: i can not change my code to your solution and i get error, how to i can be have random array lenght in this my code? `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=29; index=29`

Comment: I pointed you to the error but changing the code is up to you according to your needs, you can have two arrays(one for 12 and one for >7) or you can change `max_value` to `29` in the case of `12` , it's all up to you